# Issue related to google Chrome for Border-Radius

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have follwing css class

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="password"], form select, form textarea {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 2px 0;
}
```

and following html and Java Script:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:300px;" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click here" class="medium required" onclick="return validate();"/>

<script language="javascript">
    function validate()
    {
         if (document.getElementById('txt1').value == '') {

            document.getElementById('txt1').style.borderLeft = "5px solid red";

            return false;
        }


    }
</script>
```

It works in Mozila but in google Chrome whenever validation fires inputbox gets css exctly applied in javascript but it also creates top and bottom border of 1px solid

you can check this example on : http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/VFBT3/3/

how can i solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: That is weird. Minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/VFBT3/13/ Another even more minimal: http://jsfiddle.net/VFBT3/14/

Comment: Very odd - you've definitely discovered a bug. You can get it to disappear by changing the input's width or the border width (for example, try "8px solid red" instead of 5).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug with `border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;` and `-webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;` If you remove that from the CSS, then there is no issue with Chrome

cf - http://jsfiddle.net/VFBT3/20/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems you have caught some bug.But you can also do this thing like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VFBT3/46/

CSS

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="password"], form       select, form textarea {border: none;height: 20px;vertical-align: top;}
    div{width: 305px;height: 20px;border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;}
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

HTML:

```
<form style="margin: 20px;">
     <div>
<input type="text" id="txt1" style="width:300px;" />
   </div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click here" class="medium required" onclick="return validate();"/>

</form>
```

JS will be same.